# Does set of rational numbers with odd denominators form a group with binary operation of $+$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rational-numbers

> Does set of rational numbers with odd denominators form a group with
>   binary operation of $+$?

I think no, because it doesn't have an identity element since $0$ is not in the set because it doesn't have a denominator.

Can I say $0$ *does not have a denominator*, so it doesn't have an odd denominator?

Comment: Of course $0$ has a denominator. Any denominator is a denominator for $0$.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the phrase _"having an odd denominator"_ is maybe not quite well-defined, as it is hard to define _the_ denominator of a fraction. You might have to be more specific about what you mean by that statement in order for anyone to provide a valid answer =).

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain, I see. I think in this case we can assume fractions that have been reduced to the maximum with odd (an non-zero) denominators.

Comment: It would help you to use the concept of "subgroup". If you use the operation of a larger set which you know to be a group, checking whether it's a subgroup is fairly simpler than checking the group axioms. Hence here the question is whether it's a subgroup of $(\mathbf{Q},+)$. It's indeed the case (it's even a subring).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it forms a group. It has an identity element, which is $0\left(=\frac01\right)$.

Comment: $0/1 = 0/2 = 0$. How can we then justify that $0$ *is* a rational number with an odd denominator? Only then it can be in the set.

Comment: @Sun In the same way we justfy that $\frac 26$ is a rational number with odd denominator.

Comment: If your question really just mentions the “set of rational numbers with odd denominators”, then it doesn't make sense. But my guess is that the idea is to work with the set of those rational numbers which *can* be written as $\frac ab$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and $b$ odd.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, your guess is right. It's the latter. Any rational number which *can* be written with odd denominator.

Comment: @Gae.S., spot on. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Let $O\subset \mathbb Q$ denote the set of rational numbers such that the denominator is odd when written as a fraction where the numerator and denominator are relatively prime. Note that $\mathbb Z\subset O$, in particular $0\in O$ (note that even though $0=\tfrac{0}{n}$ is true for all integers $n>0$, the pair $(0,n)$ is relatively prime only when $n=\pm 1$, so the definition still works in this case).

You ask whether $O$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ under addition. And this is true, since
$$
\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}
$$
has $bd$ odd if $b,d$ are both odd, so if $(a,b)=(c,d)=1$ then since $(ad+bc,bd)=1$ it follows that the sum of two elements of $O$ is also in $O$.

EDIT: It's been pointed out in the comments that the previous sentence is incorrect: it need not be the case that $(ad+bc,bd)=1$ under these hypotheses. However, that claim is actually irrelevant to the argument! After reducing the fraction, the denominator will (by definition) be a divisor of $bd$ which is odd. Since all divisors of an odd number are also odd, the claim follows.

Comment: How does zero not have such a representation? Doesn't $\frac{0}{1}$ work?

Comment: No, because $(0,1)=0$: the numerator and denominator are not relatively prime.

Comment: Are you sure? [This link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integers_Coprime_to_Zero) seems to say otherwise.

Comment: Good point, I was wrong. Fixing my answer.

Comment: How does $(a, b)=(c, d)=1$ imply $(ad+bc, bd)=1$?

Comment: Ooh, it doesn't. For example take $a=1$, take $b=d=p$ to be an odd prime, and take $c=p-1$. Then $(a,b)=(c,d)=1$ whereas $(ad+bc,bd)=(p^2,p^2)=p^2$.

Answer (score -1):

The family $\Bbb Q_{(2)}:=\{\frac{a}{b}:a,b\in\Bbb Z\;\land\;2\nmid b\}$ of rationals "with odd denominator" is an integral domain, a subring of $\Bbb Q$ but not a field as $\frac{3}{4}\notin\Bbb Q_{(2)},\frac{4}{3}\in\Bbb Q_{(2)}$.

In particular, $\Bbb Q_{(2)}=\Bbb Z[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{7},\frac{1}{11},\dots]$ and for each prime $p>2$ we have $\Bbb Q_{(p)}:=\{\frac{a}{b}:a,b\in\Bbb Z\;\land\;p\nmid b\}=\Bbb Z[\frac{1}{2},\dots]$ adjoining to $\Bbb Z$ all prime reciprocals except $\frac{1}{p}$. To see this simply note that $\frac{ab'-ba'}{bb'},\frac{aa'}{bb'}\in\Bbb Q_{(p)}$ is true whenever $\frac{a}{b},\frac{a'}{b'}\in\Bbb Q_{(p)}$ where $2\nmid b,b'$.